# Not able to select google map drop down value

Tags: angularjs, cordova, google-maps, ionic-framework

I am developing a hybrid mobile app. 
I followed below link to get google location for mobile app.
On typing I am getting the list of location in a drop down but as soon as select a location the drop down hides and I am unable to select a value in Iphone and android.This problem is only in Mobile device.

```
Visit <http://jsfiddle.net/mwDQr/1/>
```

[image]

Comment: `as soon as I select a location drop down hides` that sounds like correct behaviour, when you click on suggested element it should select it and hide the suggestion, what's wrong with that?

Comment: Yes, when i am clicking on any of suggested element the box gets hide.I am not getting any error also.

Comment: The select box hides? Is the code in jsfiddle exactly the same as you sue in your app?

Comment: Yes, I am using same code base.

Comment: Is the model set after you click on dropbox, might it be that input is to wide after selecting and it drops of screen?

Comment: You might want to check https://github.com/driftyco/ionic/issues/1798. It solved my problem yesterday.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that google dynamically adds elements that need the data-tap-disabled property, so you'll have to manually add the property after google has added these elements to the dom.

```
$scope.disableTap = function() {
        var container = document.getElementsByClassName('pac-container');
        angular.element(container).attr('data-tap-disabled', 'true');
        var backdrop = document.getElementsByClassName('backdrop');
        angular.element(backdrop).attr('data-tap-disabled', 'true');
        angular.element(container).on("click", function() {
            document.getElementById('pac-input').blur();
        });
    };
```

now add ng-change='disableTap()' to your input:

```
<input id="pac-input" type="text" placeholder="Search Location" data-tap-disabled="true" ng-change='disableTap()' ng-model="search">
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not using this module/directive: https://github.com/wpalahnuk/ngAutocomplete

Here is an example in Ionic:

```js
angular.module('app', ['ionic','ngAutocomplete', 'ngMap'])

.controller('MapCtrl', ['$scope', 'NgMap', 
function($scope, NgMap) {
  
  $scope.autocomplete;
  
  NgMap.getMap().then(function(map) {
    $scope.map = map;
    var input = document.getElementById('Autocomplete');
    $scope.autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input);
    $scope.autocomplete.bindTo('bounds', map);
    google.maps.event.addListener($scope.autocomplete, "place_changed", function() {
        var place = $scope.autocomplete.getPlace();
        if (place && place.geometry) {
          map.setCenter(place.geometry.location);
          
          $scope.data = {
            lat: place.geometry.location.lat(),
            lng: place.geometry.location.lng()
          };
          $scope.$apply();
          console.log($scope.data);
        }
    });
        
  });

}]);
```

```css
#map {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100% !important;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
  <title></title>

  <script src="//maps.google.com/maps/api/js?libraries=visualization,drawing,geometry,places"></script>
  <link href="//code.ionicframework.com/nightly/css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="//code.ionicframework.com/nightly/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>
  <script src="//rawgit.com/allenhwkim/angularjs-google-maps/master/build/scripts/ng-map.js"></script>
  <script src="//rawgit.com/wpalahnuk/ngAutocomplete/master/src/ngAutocomplete.js"></script>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">
  
  <script src="app.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-app="app" ng-controller="MapCtrl">
  <ion-pane>
    <ion-header-bar class="bar-positive">
      <h1 class="title">Ionic map</h1>
    </ion-header-bar>
    <ion-content class="has-header">
      <input type="text" id="Autocomplete" class="form-control" ng-autocomplete ng-model="result1" />
      <div>result: {{result1}}</div>
      <ng-map zoom="6" class="map">
        <marker position="{{data.lat}}, {{data.lng}}"></marker>
      </ng-map>
    </ion-content>
  </ion-pane>
</body>

</html>
```

Or the Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/d3eE7PENJFEzbla4os8z?p=preview